# jQuery page slider, based on JSON data source

Tags: jquery, json, slider, jquery-slider

this is my first post in SO, I'd like to reach the result shown here http://builtbybuffalo.com/project/view/bored-of-southsea/date/desc

As you can see the page uses a dynamic jquery slider, with the content taken from a JSON source.
I need your help in **understanding the process**, and later I'll try to recreate this amazing slider.

As you can see, if you click the "previous" and "next" button the url page doesn'change, and it loads the code from a json file.

Would you be so kind to help me in finding this solution?
I really do thank you for your suggestions.

Hugs!
Marco

Comment: Have you tried looking at the source code? project-next-prev.js is pretty succinct.

Answer (score 0):

What you can do is use $.getJSON to get the data (it must be well formed json see http://www.json.org/) You want to return an array of object in the order of your slides.

{"items":[
{
"thumb":"",
"large":""
}
]}

Have a template set, if you aim for images only might be worth having both thumbnail and large images URL, use the thumbnail to create the button.

You can store the large URL on each. When one is clicked, if it is not loaded create a new image file in which you load the URL, when it is ready append the newly create image tag and do transitions if necessary.